# UISearchBar.appearance() not working in iOS13

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, appearance

So I wanted to do some custom styling on my search bars inside my navigation controllers with large titles that are setup like this;

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

To do the styling I want to apply it platform wide, so I don't have to style it inside every single view that I'll be building. So I went along, and thought to hook up a few things from iOS13 as well like this;

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self])

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchBar.barStyle                           = searchBarStyle
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor    = searchBarBackground
    searchBar.searchTextField.textColor          = searchBarTextColor
    searchBar.tintColor                          = searchBarTint
}
```

After running this, it is not working as expected. Only the tintColor is being set, and nothing else. As soon as I go to my view controller and do the following it works;

```
var searchController = UISearchController()

searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .red
```

Any ideas what I'm missing inside the appearance setup to make this work the same way as in my view controller?

Comment: As a confirmation, it works properly on iOS 12-, correct?

Comment: Everything works on iOS 12, but it seems that this whole large titles and searchbar feature is broken and Apple delivered really awful api's.